# How to exclude XSD elements from documentation

Tags: xsd

I have an XSD that I'm editing, and, using a tool such as XMLSpy or oXygen, I'd like to generate user documentation for the XSD. However, I'd like to exclude certain elements from the documentation (based on user requirements). What would be the best approach to do this?

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Without stating anything about how you wish to document your XSDs, you're asking how not to document certain elements.  About all that could be answered would be suggest that you simply not add `xsd:annotation/xsd:documentation` to any elements you wish not to document.

Comment: When I say "generate documentation", I mean to generate schema documentation in HTML, Word, PDF, etc., format, in an automated fashion using the capabilities of an XML editor application.

Comment: The documentation capabilities of various tools will vary, as will any features for excluding certain elements.   Your question as currently written is unclear, or too broad, or out of scope because it's asking for a tool recommendation, or some combination of the above three.  If you don't rework it, it'll be surely be closed.

Comment: I'm not asking for a tool recommendation. Perhaps there is a tool-independent methodology that others have used in the past. (e.g.: 1. Apply an attribute; 2. Apply a transformation to remove elements with said attribute; 3. Generate documentation for the output).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Removing elements from documentation is a three-part process:

**1. Add an attribute to the the elements to indicate whether or not they should be documented.**

Following is a code sample showing an XSD with three elements, and a new attribute, `generateDocumentation`, that indicates whether the element should be documented.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="documentation.xslt"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
           xmlns:mc="http://www.mycompany.com" 
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mycompany.com ./doc.xsd" 
           elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:element name="DocumentedElement" mc:generateDocumentation="true"/>
    <xs:element name="UndocumentedElement" mc:generateDocumentation="false"/>
    <xs:element name="DefaultElement"/>
</xs:schema>
```

Specifics on how to extend XSD with custom attributes can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36289219/extend-xsd-with-custom-attributes/36318451#36318451).

Note that, in this example, elements without the `generateDocumentation` attribute defined will be documented by default.

**2. Apply a transformation to remove elements with attribute values indicating that they should not be documented.**

The following XSLT will remove elements that have `mc:generateDocumentation="false"` or `mc:generateDocumentation="0"`, and will strip the resulting white space:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                xmlns:mc="http://www.mycompany.com">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <!-- Identity transform -->
    <xsl:template match="/ | @* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Undocumented elements -->
    <xsl:template match="*[@mc:generateDocumentation='false'] | *[@mc:generateDocumentation='0']"/>

    <!-- Strip white space -->
    <xsl:template match="*/text()[normalize-space()]">
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*/text()[not(normalize-space())]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This transformation produces the XSD with the specified elements removed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="documentation.xslt"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:mc="http://www.mycompany.com" 
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mycompany.com ./doc.xsd" 
           elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:element name="DocumentedElement" nc:generateDocumentation="true"/>
    <xs:element name="DefaultElement"/>
</xs:schema>
```

**3. Use the tool of your choice to generate the user documentation.**

Answer (score 0):

There's no tool-independent way to exclude elements from documentation.

- There's `xsd:annotation/xsd:appinfo` for application-oriented data.
- There's `xsd:annotation/xsd:documentation` for human-oriented data.

XSDs are XML, so writing an XSLT transformation is certainly one way to generate documentation.  Note, however, that the semantics of XSD are complex enough that the exclusion of any given element will be trivial relative to the rest of the task.